# C# WPF pushing worker informaton from worker.cs to a Home.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, worker

I am pretty new in WPF and I tried for days now.

In my MainWindow.xaml.cs I create a new Instance of my Worker.

```cs
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.run_Worker();
    }
```

The MainWindow.xaml loads the Home.xaml on startup:

ContentSource="/Pages/Home.xaml"

In my Home.xaml I have a ProgressBar and a Infolog.

In the Worker I tried something like this:

```cs
 Home home = new Home();
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
 {
      home.InfoLog.Content = "test";
 }));
```

Ihis Working if I put the code for the worker into the Home.xaml.cs but not If put the worker in a seperated class and push the data into a new Instance of Home.

Is there any way to push Information to different classes / Page and without using a new Instance of Home()?

Thank you :)

Comment: you can pass `this` into new Worker() and make it a private property of worker. So: `public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Worker worker = new Worker(this);
        worker.run_Worker();
    }`

`class Worker{
private MainWindow lthis{get;set;} 
 public Worker(MainWindow lthis){
   this.lthis = lthis;
}

}`

You will also have to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to Invoke any UI changes.

Comment: Then I have the MainWindow available for the worker. But what about the Home()? There are the elements that display the worker progress. I still can't access them with this way. Or meybee I didnt understsand you :)

Comment: You will need to add an x:Name in your MainWindow.xaml on the element that represents `<Home></>` Like <Home x:Name="Home"></> then you will be able to access that element from the code behind. I added some code below.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass "this" into new Worker() and make it a private property of worker. 
So:

UI

```
<Window x:Class="testappreddit.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testappreddit"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="525"
Height="350"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
<StackPanel>
    <Home x:Name="home" />

</StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Backend

```
public class MainWindow{

    public MainWindow()
    { 
       InitializeComponent(); 
       Worker worker = new Worker(this); 
       worker.run_Worker(); 
    }
}

public class Worker
{
 private MainWindow lthis{get;set;}
 public Worker(MainWindow lthis)
 {
   this.lthis = lthis; 
 }
 public void run_worker(){
    while(lthis != default(MainWindow)){
       DoWork();
       Thread.Sleep(5000);

    }
 }
 private void DoWork(){
     Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
          lthis.home.InfoLog.Content = "test";
        }));
  }

}

public class Home
{
   public InfoLog InfoLog {get;set;}

}

public class InfoLog
{
  public string Content {get;set;}
}
```

You will also have to use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

to Invoke any UI changes